# Covariance matrix of the variables of a dataset with very small values/

Tags: matlab, numpy, covariance, scientific-computing

I have a dataset including very small values therefore as you try to compute covariance matrix you conclude NAN values. How should I change the data as I am able to scale those very small values in the computation ?

I am using MATLAB but any other alternative is also okay for me.

Comment: You probably have NaNs in your dataset.

Comment: How small is small? How are you computing the covariance matrix? With `cov`? If that's the case then I don't see how you could end up with `NaN` unless @OlegKomarov is correct.

Comment: `Inf` in your dataset can also result in `NaN` output. Use `isfinite` to check.

Comment: Erogol, did my answer help you?

Comment: @A.Donda unfortunately not since in that way values converges zero at the end. I used to scale the values.

Answer (score 1):

As has become clear from the comments, the problem are not small values but NaNs in your data. If you have the *Statistics Toolbox*, you can use [`nancov`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nancov.html), which ignores observations (rows) that contain NaNs. If not, it is simple to implement:

```
cov(x(~any(isnan(x), 2), :))
```

If you have many NaNs in your data, you might get a better estimate of the covariance matrix if you compute the covariance separately for each pair of variables, and exclude rows containing NaNs only specifically for the given pair. A drawback of this approach is however that the resulting matrix may no longer be positive definite.